# How to get updates from a row details template

Tags: xml, wpf, wpf-controls

I want the ability to edit data being displayed in the row dtetailsTemplate control. is it possible?

I have a grid view within RowDetailsTemplate gridview which I'm trying to updat on it but couldn't get the changes. it always returns the value unchanged.

The Data grid:

```
<HDataGridEx x:Name="dgrd1" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding MEDICALRECORDCOPYPRINTING_HMEINFO_LIST}" HeadersVisibility="All" IsShowCheckHeader="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ShowRowIndex="True" CanUserSelectRowHeader="False"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding MEDICALRECORDCOPYPRINTING_HMEINFO_ITEM}" GridLinesVisibility="None" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" RowHeight="35"
                     AlternatingRowBackground="{StaticResource AlternatingRowBackgroundBrush}" >
```

---

the Row details template inside the Data grid:

```
<HDataGridEx.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border x:Name="grdPrnt" Background="{StaticResource RowExpanderBackground}" Margin="3"
                            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=HDataGridEx}, Path=DataContext}" >
            <HDataGridEx x:Name="dgrd2" GridLinesVisibility="All" IsReadOnly="False"
                                             HeadersVisibility="Column" HasRowHeaderStatus="False"
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding MEDICALRECORDCOPYPRINTING_HMEINFO_LIST_SECOND , Mode=TwoWay}"
                                             CanUserSelectRowHeader="False"
                                             SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                             Margin="5">
            </HDataGridEx>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</HDataGridEx.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

the save Command:

```
<HButton Content="{LanguageResource Source=MS, Path=Alias.MSD_012493, Description='Modification'}" Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonSaveStyle}"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" PermissionManager.ButtonPermission="Write" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgrd2}" Visibility="{Binding SAVEVISIBILITY}" />
```

and the value in the below condition is always true:

```
if (this.MEDICALRECORDCOPYPRINTING_HMEINFO_LIST_SECOND.GetChanges().Count <= 0)
{
    MsgBox.Display("MSMCN_001619", MessageType.MSG_TYPE_INFORMATION, Owner: this.OwnerWindow, TimeSpan: 1000);
    // NO DATA CHANGE
    return;
}
```